# how to you do situation like IF in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, `A`

```
List<int> A = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I also have a bool variable `S`. I want to copy `A` into another list using LINQ, with a condition: if `S` is false then copy the negative value of each element in `A` (e.g. {-1,-2..}) else it will be the same, like {1,2..}

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I can make no sense of it as it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, that's indeed possible:

```
var B = (from item in A
         select S ? item : -item).ToList();
```

Or, using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
var B = A.Select(item => S ? item : -item).ToList();
```

You can even do that without using the [ternary conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a):

```
var B = A.Select(item => {
    if (S) {
        return item;
    } else {
        return -item;
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning an alternative without the conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

By using the ternary `?:` operator

```
A.Select(a=>s?a:-a).ToList()
```

it means that for each element `a` in `A`, it will add an element to the list having the value `a` if `s` is true, and `-a` if not